# Form not validation failed on hitting the url twice

Tags: django

I have one model form for entering product detail. After submitting it I am validating this form in a view and returning another HTML page. It is working fine.

Now on another page, where I am coming after submitting the form, I am doing 2 things:
1. Refreshing the page by clicking on the refresh icon: In this case, validation is happening as usual.

I am facing a problem when I am doing this 2nd thing:

2. When I hit the same URL again then the form validation is failing.

Why? Can anyone please help me?

Url for getting the form:

```
 /createProduct
```

Url for submitting the form:

```
/saveProduct
```

This is my model form:

```
#Model form for Product model
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form- 
control','placeholder':'Product Name','name':'product-name'})) 
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','selected':'Select Product Category','name':'product-category'}),queryset=Category.objects.all())
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Product Description','name':'product-description'})) 

price =forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Product Price','name':'product-price'}))
contact =forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Provide your contact no','name':'poster-contact'}))



class Meta:
    model = Product
    #fields = ('name','category', 'image','description','price')
    fields = ('name','category','description','price','contact')
```

This is the view for rendering product form:

```
def create_product_fn(request):
 form = ProductForm()
 return render(request, 'olx/product/create_product.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the view where I am coming after submitting the form:

```
def  save_new_product(request):
 if request.user.is_authenticated:

   formToSave = ProductForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

   if formToSave.is_valid():

     # Instead of saving it store it in session to save it later 

     request.session['save_product_form_data_1'] = request.POST
     request.session['save_product_form_data_2'] = request.FILES

   else:
      # if form is not valid, returning to form to enter product detail again
      return create_product_fn(request,info)

   return render(request, 'olx/product/upload_product_photos.html')  
 else:
   print('session expired') 
   return render(request, 'olx/login.html')
```

Comment: add your urls for which problem arise

Comment: Failing how? What happens?